# What is the difference between »arbeiten«, »werken« and »wirken«?

Tags: synonym

I am especially interested in the difference between the latter two verbs, *werken* and *wirken*.

Comment: Was hast Du mit Wörterbüchern selbst herausfinden können?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Arbeiten** has a broad meaning. It drops in where someone or something is working or functioning.

> Er arbeitet gerade an seiner Steuererklärung
>
> Die Maschine arbeitet nicht richtig.

There also is the derivative **sich abarbeiten** which means **to labor**.

> Er arbeitete sich an seiner Steuererklärung ab. (he's exhausted and probably angry.)

---

**Werken** is seldom used. It's a synonym of *arbeiten* then.

> Lasst uns daran werken!

And then there is the school subject *das Werken*, which is a substantive made from that verb and means *handicrafts*.

---

**Wirken** in its broadest sense means *to cause an effect*. Use it when you want to focus on the effect of work. Most times derivatives as *bewirken*, *mitwirken*, *entgegenwirken* etc. are used.

> *Chlorix* wirkt gegen Schmutz und Urinstein.
>
> Du musst warten, bis es wirkt.
>
> Händel wirkte hauptsächlich in Hamburg und London. (as tofro suggested)
>
> Das bewirkt gar nichts.
>
> Sie wirkte bei vielen wichtigen Projekten mit.
>
> Diese Kraft wirkt der anderen Kraft entgegen.

Note the derivative *verwirken* has a complete different meaning: *to forfeit.*

Comment: Note you're missing an important notation of "wirken": *Händel war ein berühmter Komponist und wirkte hauptsächlich in Hamburg und London.*

Comment: I found it was covered by *mitwirken* but you are right, it's another simple case.